# Finding out UISnapBehaviour's item

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In my application I have a bunch of UISnapBehaviours each with a unique view attached to it.

I'd like to do the following:

1) Add a view to a UIGravityBehaviour

2) Iterate through the Snap Behaviours

3) **Find out the item that is the same as the view that was just added to the Gravity Behaviour**

4) Remove the Snap Behaviour that contains that view from the animator

My problem is there doesn't seem to be any public API in UISnapBehaviour to discover which item it was inited with...

I looked at UISnapBehavior and UIDynamicBehavior's documentation and found nothing. Am I missing something? Is this at all possible?